# Passing parameters to an AJAX modal popup?

Tags: c#, ajax, code-behind

So after some fumbling, I have an aspx page running inside an AJAX popup (using iframe).  However, this aspx page accepts several parameters.  The program used to open a JavaScript popup to send the parameters, like this:

```
string DeptID = ((User)Session ["User"]).UserDepartmentID.ToString();
string url = "EditTables.aspx?title=Edit Asset Manufacturers&prompt=Manufacturer Name&method=GetManufacturers&name=ManufacturerName&value=ManufacturerID&deptid=" + DeptID;
string script = "window.open ('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=500, height=135, left=' + ((screen.width - 530) / 2) + ', top=' + ((screen.height - 80) / 2));";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript (this.GetType(), "script", script, true);
```

However, since I am converting to an AJAX popup, this code currently looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Test Button" />
   <ajax:ModalPopupExtender  
      ID="mp1Manufacturer" 
      PopupControlID="Panl1"
      runat="server" 
      BehaviorID="Button1_DropDownExtender" 
      DynamicServicePath="" 
      TargetControlID="Button1">
   </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">  
   <iframe style=" width: 500px; height: 500px;" id="irm1" src="EditTables.aspx?title=Edit Asset Manufacturers&prompt=TEST&method=GetManufacturers&name=ManufacturerName&value=ManufacturerID&deptid=c9c1f7ff-65bc-4687-90bb-39488db508b4" runat="server"></iframe> 
<br/>  
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />  
</asp:Panel>
```

Note the hardcoded values for the src page.  That's not workable for reusability of the page.  Is there a way to call this AJAX popup from server side and supply the parameters via my code behind page?

Comment: There are a couple of options. The better way is to use an UpdatePanel instead, as it abstracts the iframe concept. The other is to use ASP.net scripting features on the markup. <iframe ... src="<%=this.PropertyInTheCodeBehind%>"... />

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do you have an example of one of these methods?  Would prefer to work via the code behind, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Test Button" />
   <ajax:ModalPopupExtender  
      ID="mp1Manufacturer" 
      PopupControlID="Panl1"
      runat="server" 
      BehaviorID="Button1_DropDownExtender" 
      DynamicServicePath="" 
      TargetControlID="Button1">
   </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">  
   <%-- using the scripting tag below, you use the IFrameSrc property on your code behind behind to render the correct URL. --%>
   <iframe style=" width: 500px; height: 500px;" id="irm1" src="<%=this.IFrameSrc%>"></iframe> 
<br/>  
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />  
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in the code behind.

```
public String IFrameSrc
{
  get
  {
    //Here you get a chance to manipulate the string in the code behind however you see fit.
    return "EditTables.aspx?title=Edit Asset Manufacturers&prompt=TEST&method=GetManufacturers&name=ManufacturerName&value=ManufacturerID&deptid=c9c1f7ff-65bc-4687-90bb-39488db508b4";
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  Using your code, I am now getting a blank popup with the words "Bad Request - Invalid URL" at the top.  I tried to put a break point on the line in the IFrameSrc method, but it never hits it.

Comment: Whoa, never mind.  I got it!  I just had to remove the runat="server" from the iframe.  Thank you, JPortillo!

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked that. Glad you figured it out.